# Qt Creator on Fedora 25: "No valid kits found"

Tags: qt, qt-creator, fedora-25

If I try to open an existing project in Qt Creator I always get "No valid kits found".

I found a lot of Q&A around this, but on my installation I am not able to select a valid Qt version because:

In Build&Run->Kids->Desktop->QtVersion: None

I can not see any other entry in this field.

As already mentioned: It is a Fedora 25 x86_64 version.

Qt Creator gives in comand line:

> Warning: No kit 'qt.57.gcc_64_kit' found. Continuing.

Is this a file which should exist somewhere? Can it be downloaded somewhere? Manual config seems to be not possible, because qt version can not be selected.

Is there any package which I did not have installed? Is there any meta package which I can use to get a valid installation?

What I have installed:

> rpm -qa | grep qt5

```
    dbusmenu-qt5-0.9.3-0.11.20150604.fc24.x86_64
    qt5-qtbase-gui-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtwebchannel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qttools-static-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtconfiguration-devel-0.3.1-2.fc24.x86_64
    adwaita-qt5-0.4-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtsvg-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtbase-common-5.7.0-3.fc25.noarch
    qt5-qtlocation-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qttools-libs-designer-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtx11extras-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtserialport-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qttools-devel-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtconfiguration-0.3.1-2.fc24.x86_64
    qt5-qtwayland-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qttools-libs-clucene-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtlocation-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    quazip-qt5-0.7.2-1.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qttools-libs-designercomponents-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qttools-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtenginio-devel-1.6.1-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-linguist-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtwebsockets-devel-5.7.0-1.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtconnectivity-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtsvg-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtquickcontrols-5.7.0-1.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtwayland-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-devel-5.7.0-9.fc25.noarch
    qt5-qtxmlpatterns-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtwebkit-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtserialport-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtaccountsservice-devel-0.6.0-2.fc24.x86_64
    qt5-qttools-libs-help-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtmultimedia-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtimageformats-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtsensors-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtdoc-5.7.0-1.fc25.noarch
    qt5-designer-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtbase-static-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtenginio-1.6.1-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qt3d-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtbase-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtdeclarative-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-rpm-macros-5.7.0-9.fc25.noarch
    qt5-qhelpgenerator-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtwebsockets-5.7.0-1.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtconnectivity-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    phonon-qt5-4.9.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtscript-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtwebchannel-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-gstreamer-devel-1.2.0-11.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtaccountsservice-0.6.0-2.fc24.x86_64
    phonon-qt5-backend-gstreamer-4.9.0-1.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtscript-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtbase-devel-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtx11extras-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    polkit-qt5-1-0.112.0-8.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qdoc-5.7.0-3.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtdeclarative-static-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtwebkit-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-gstreamer-1.2.0-11.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtdeclarative-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtsensors-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qttools-common-5.7.0-3.fc25.noarch
    qt5-qtmultimedia-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qtxmlpatterns-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
    qt5-qt3d-devel-5.7.0-2.fc25.x86_64
```

Comment: Where did you install Qt Creator from? The Fedora repo or the Qt project website?

Comment: @Venemo: with dnf package management

Comment: Can you please give us the output of `rpm -qa | grep qt5` (maybe using a pastebin site)?

Comment: @Venemo: I added the installed packet list...

Comment: By the way, I assume you mean *kits* and NOT *kids*...

Comment: @Venemo, kids do run a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it:

qtcreator was not able to find my qmake installation, because in the fedora packages qmake is:

> -rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 2921520 19. Jul 14:51 /usr/bin/qmake-qt5

Adding a softlink to

> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18  5. Dez 17:17 /usr/bin/qmake -> /usr/bin/qmake-qt5

did NOT help!

You have to point to the correct qmake via :

Build&Run -> Kits -> Manual -> Desktop -> Qt-Version -> Manage -> "Select qmake with file-browser"

Now it seems to find a qt version.
In "Details" the dialog prints "Qt version 5.7.0 for Desktop"

Why there is not a simple output: "Can not find qmake"?

OK, seems to be a bit special to fedora which install qmake to different file name.

Comment: In `/use/bin`, I have `qmake-qt5.sh` (selected by default, not working) and `qmake-qt5` which works.

Answer (score 5):

I also develop with Qt Creator on Fedora 25, and it works for me.

Here is how I usually do it:

```
dnf install make gcc-c++ gdb
dnf install qt5*-devel
dnf install qt-creator
```

After this, I've got a working Qt Creator configuration on a fresh Fedora 25 (that I just installed from scratch yesterday).

To be honest, I'm not sure what you might have been doing wrong, but I have a few ideas:

- Did you upgrade from a previous OS version or maybe copy the configuration of a previous Qt Creator version to your new installation?
- Check that you have a compiler and build environment (`make`, `gcc`, ...) installed
- If its configuration is corrupt, you could try deleting `~/.config/QtProject` and Qt Creator might recognize your stuff.
- Try to delete the `*.pro.user` file of your project if it may have been generated by a previous Qt Creator version

In any case, you can fix the configuration relatively easily.

- Go to Tools -> Options
- Select Build & Run
- On the Compilers tab you should see your installed compiler in the auto-detected section. If you have a compiler installed but it isn't recognized, add it here manually.
- On the Qt Versions tab, the version I installed from the Fedora repo (currently 5.7.0) appears in the Manual section (even though I didn't add it manually). You can add it by browsing to `/usr/bin/qmake-qt5`.
- On the Kits tab, I have a single Manual entry called Desktop, which is basically set to use the compiler and Qt version mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. As you see in my answer qtcreator was simply not able to see my qmake. As you pointed out, qmake is installed on fedora as "/usr/bin/qmake-qt5." and qtcreator did not find it. I have to manually setup as described in my answer.

Comment: @Klaus That's interesting because I didn't have to add it manually, but it somehow still found it... Not sure how this could happen.

Comment: Yes, colleagues have done "nearly" the same installation  process and have no problems ;) Maybe the Q&A will help others to find a solution if running in the same mystery. "Nearly" means: I have no idea what we did different :-)

Answer (score 2):

Based on  @SteeveDroz comment that worked for me on Fedora 29:

Remove the path to the shell script and select `/us/bin/qmake-qt5`. 
Now it doesn't complain about the wrong version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "No valid kits found" error can be caused by many things (e.g. missing g++ compiler). Here's a video I just uploaded that shows a clean install of Qt 5.13 on a clean install of Fedora 30 KDE:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQKoNwg5afU

Comment: I did not watch videos at all for programming questions. A well written text with some links is far enough. It feels like asking for a way to somewhere and someone sends me a video from driving this road...