# Qt Version Is Not Properly Installed - no suitable kits found

Tags: c++, qt

EDITED:
If you're having problems like this

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Just downgrade the version you installed and avoid the alpha one. In my case, I installed Qt 6.3.0-alpha. That's it, hope it helps.

*Thanks @drescherjm for the explanation in the comment section.

Comment: It's on Win 10. Lemme post a pict of what I selected when installing it.

Comment: It is not properly installed. Reinstall it and include MSVC and Sources as well.

Comment: @Anurag There is no need to include sources and MSVC if he does not need it. If he wants to use MinGW, then he should install only MinGW version of Qt and the corresponsing compiler.

Comment: Still not resolved though.

Comment: @Riiko, show details on Kits tab. By the way, if you mouseover the kit it will show the tooltip with problems/warnings (there are some as it shows warning icon)

Comment: There are some sus warnings though, "Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install", "Invalid Qt version"

Comment: Qt trouble shooting is a known nightmare. Had such issues years ago ( never used Qt since that ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978510/qt-creator-on-fedora-25-no-valid-kits-found

Comment: It says version 6.3 is an alpha release. You should probably not use that. You probably want to install version 6.2 instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with linux so I don't get the thing there.

Comment: @drescherjm I thought it might be the case, since I ever used Qt 6.~ which was lower than the 6.3.0 version. I reinstalled my windows, so I lost the older one.

Comment: Can't you go back to the online installer remove 6.3 and install 6.2?  An alpha version is the early release. I would expect bugs and things not to work properly. Unless you are an expert or have a lot of time to work with developers to file bug reports and to fix problems you probably should not use it.

Comment: @drescherjm It's as what I expected and what you explained :)

Comment: Finally, it's working now